# Different results in base R plot with plot(x,y) and plot(x~y)

Tags: r, plot

I am plotting a graph for a parameter x which represents energy usage vs y which represents data-time in `%y-%m-%d %h:%m:%s` format. Now, when I issue `plot(x,y, other parameters)` I get a box plot, and when I execute `plot(x~y, other parameters)` I get a completely different graph (with spikes). The only difference between the two plot commands is the way `x,y` parameters are passed.

I searched for relevant document but could not get useful information. Please share your thoughts on this.

[image: Graph outputs with above commands]

Comment: Formulas pass the `y` variable first; see `?plot.formula`. As for what type of plot gets drawn if you don't specify, that can vary a bit depending on what you're passing.

Comment: The comma is not a replacement for a tilde. `plot(x,y)` is the same as `plot(y~x)`. The difference is a side effect of how statistical models are usually written with the response on the left; but when data is listed as ordered pairs for plotting, the response is usually on the right.

Answer (score 1):

generic plot uses `plot(x,y)`, where x and y are the coordinates in a simple scatter plots.
`plot(y~x)` `?plot.formula` is for plotting a formula. As @alistaire mentioned y~x

Comment: thanks all for this information. @ed_sans One more thing, when x axis value being passed is a date/time, how come on x axis its just printing day labels?

Comment: take a look at `axis` ? something like this would do `axis(1, x$Date, format(x$Date, "%b %d"))` with the preferable format ofcourse.